# Kestrel starting from VS2019 : page ok, starting from executable : 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http-status-code-404, appsettings, kestrel

Just created asp.Net core project.

- From VS2019 : I have the requested page.
- From the debug executable : Page not found error 404.

using : http://localhost:5555/swagger/index.html on both.

=================================================

Does not work (executable direct)

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:5555
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Prj\Personnel\WallyRest\WallyRest\bin\Debug\net5.0
```

=================================================

Does work fine (Started from Visual Studio 2019 : Debug - Any CPU)

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Overriding address(es) 'http://localhost:5115'. Binding to endpoints defined in UseKestrel() instead.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:5555
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Prj\Personnel\WallyREst\WallyRest
```

=================================================

Appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },

  "Kestrel": {
    "EndPoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://0.0.0.0:5555" // ";http://pd140356:8181;http://*:6666",
//      "Url": "http://localhost:5555"
      }
    }
  },

  "AllowedHosts": "*",

  // "urls": "http://*:5115;http://*:8888"
}
```

=================================================

I have no appsettings.Production.json

appsettings.Development.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

=================================================

ConfigureServices and Configure code:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "WallyRest", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "WallyRest v1"));
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

Comment: Something to do with the hosting environment on one being "Development" and the hosting development on the other being "Production"? Try starting with the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` set to `Development` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0))

Comment: Do you know how? Also, Do you have any idea what could be the difference in code?

Comment: It will likely be trying to read appSettings.Production.json now instead of appSettings.Development.json as it would in debug (because of the environment value defaulting to `Production`). Perhaps you have some configuration that's directly or indirectly affecting things.

Comment: Another way to test my theory might be to go to the project's properties in Visual Studio, go to "Debug", and then change the value "ASPNETCORE_Environment" there from "Development" to "Production". If you see the same behaviour in debug once this change has been made, this is likely the issue.

Comment: Your theory is exact. If I change from Dev to prod, I have the same behavior as running the executable directly. That's a very good step but the only difference is the existence of: appsettings.Development.json which I just added in the description of my problem. But I can't see how it could prevent the swagger page from appearing ???

Comment: Can you show your ConfigureServices and Configure code?

Comment: I found it!!!!! And that is because of you Llama!!!! Thank you so much!!!!!! CAn you post an answer saying to check for : "env.IsDevelopment()" like in : public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
  {
   if (env.IsDevelopment())
   {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "WallyRest v1"));
   }...     THanks!!!!

Comment: You should post your current code in your question before I can post an answer :)

Comment: @Llama GOTCHA!!! Thanks right exactly in "Configure" like you said. But that is weird because I don't remember to have chosen to do special code for Devlopment VS Production ????

Comment: Maybe you just put it in the wrong place by accident when you added it to the Configure method?

Comment: Code updated in question. I don't think I modified "Configure". I'm new to Asp.net core and little affraid of it for the moment :-). Thanks you vry much because I was looking a solution a little while.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on where Swagger ends up, so it might be possible that it goes in this block by default. Anyway, I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're seeing is down to this code:

```cs
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "WallyRest v1"));
}
```

When you run your code from Visual Studio, it normally sets the [`ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0) environment variable to "Development":

[image]

This in turn sets the environment in code to "Development" when the application starts. If this value isn't set, it will default to "Production"

Ultimately this means that `if (env.IsDevelopment())` will evaluate to `false`, as it isn't the development environment anymore, and the code within the block won't run.

The solution is to simply move your Swagger code outside this block:

```cs
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "WallyRest v1"));
```